Help with Ball Rotation and Attraction Mechanics in Leap on
I'm working on a Leap On-style game in Unity where the main mechanic involves a ball revolving around a central circle that constantly attracts the ball toward itself. The goal is for the player to press and hold the mouse button to make the ball revolve around the circle, but the ball should always be moving towards the center of the circle due to the attraction. Occasionally, objects spawn, and when the ball hits one, it should receive an upward force, pushing it away from the circle, and the player must survive as long as possible.
Here's what I've tried so far:
RotateAround: I initially used RotateAround to rotate the ball around the circle, but it didn't produce the desired results.
Tangential force: I then tried applying tangential forces to revolve the ball around the circle. However, I'm facing two main issues:

Sometimes the ball moves farther away from the circle, causing the radius to get bigger and bigger as it revolves.

In other cases, the ball gets stuck on the circumference of the circle and just keeps rotating around it without coming closer to the center.


I'm not sure how to address these issues, especially with the ball's radius either expanding or contracting too much. Any suggestions on how to better simulate the ball's revolution and attraction while keeping the mechanics intact?
Thank you in advance for any help

The effects you describe are real world physics - anything moving through space (containing only one large mass) will be on one of three trajectories:

Sub-orbital - it may travel in an arc, but that arc ends up hitting the mass.
Orbital - the object will follow a elliptical path around the mass.
Hyperbolic - the object has exceeded escape velocity/energy, hence will never return to the mass.

Note: I haven't bothered including circular obits or parabolic trajectories, since even a tiny perturbance in velocity will result in one of the three paths described above.
The root of this, is that gravity follows an inverse square law - the force of gravity drops to 1/4 if you double the distance you are from the mass.

Most likely you are applying your attractive force to the center mass (gravity?) using an inverse square formular, so you are seeing similar effects to real world physics.
In order to fix it you will need to change the physics of your simulation, some options might be:

Apply some drag to the player, this may be:

Simple - opposite the direction of movement.
Radial - reduces the velocity away from the mass.
Orbital - reduces the velocity of the rotation around the mass - but leaves the radial component alone.


Change the attractive force (towards the mass) to something other than inverse square (reciprocal or constant may be good choices).
Limit the maximum speed of the player (again maybe just the orbital or radial component).

Initially I think that applying drag may be the simplest solution, but I suspect that might be a dead end - the game won't feel right.  You will need to play with the options to see what feels right, additionally you may need more than one option.
